# In rails, how to create a self association for rows with duplicate values for a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `persons` that has an `email` column. The model `Person` should have an association called `duplicates` such that `Person.first.duplicates` would return all the `persons` with the same email.

This code works:

```
has_many :duplicates, class_name: 'Person', primary_key: 'email', foreign_key: 'email'
```

and is returning "itself" (the first person in question). I could use a lambda to filter that out so it only returns the "other" duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the association like this

```
has_many :duplicates, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'email'
```

Comment: Just tried this. This does not return the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :duplicates, -> (object) {
           where("id != ?", object.id)
         }, 
         class_name: 'Person', 
         primary_key: 'email', 
         foreign_key: 'email'
```